# Operating System not found, to install CentOS 7 on VMWare Workstation 12

Tags: linux, centos, vmware

I want to install CentOS 7 on VMWare Workstation 12. After I created a virtual machine and clicked "Power on this virtual machine", I got the following error:

[image: Operation System not found]

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you attached the ISO? And maybe also the boot order?

Comment: @TomYan Yes I attached the ISO file.

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/449235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this is probably a duplicate question which you could easily look up.

1. Make sure you attach your installation media (typically an ISO from
   the OS website) to your VMWare workstation machine
2. Make sure it is set to boot to that image file. To do this make sure it is listed as attached/powered on so that it is detected. Go in to the BIOS and set your boot order. Make sure it sees the virtual CD/USB drive and set that as priority.